# .htaccess and rewrites Rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some difficulties to create a simply htaccess for url rewriting.

What I would like is url with 3 parameters :

www.example.com
=> index.php

www.example.com/module/
=> index.php?module=$1

www.example.com/module/action/
=> index.php?module=$1&action=$2

www.example.com/module/action/1
=> index.php?module=$1&action=$2&params=$3

I did that with many tutorials, but when I try with the last one, it's failed

```
RewriteRule ^web/([^/]*)$ index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^web/([^/]*)/(.*[^/])$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^web/([^/]*)/(.*[^/])/([0-9]*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&params=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Someone could help me ?

Thanks

**Bouffe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` part of your second expression is gobbling up anything after `/action/` so you need to limit it the same as the one right before the `/` and use the `+` instead of `*`:

```
RewriteRule ^web/([^/]+)$ index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^web/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^web/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&params=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks ! I think I mixed a little url rewriting with regex with .*
I'll read more the doc

Comment: I have full like 'http://www.example.com/templates/professional_website/news.php?ac=post&id=2&p=1', then how can i implement this ? to 'https://www.example.com/templates/professional_website/news/post/2/1'